# Async Queue Stops Populating after a while

Tags: python, tiktok

I have a TikTok API that has async functions that adds items to my queue and then I have another async function that prints them. I plan to do something more with this function but since I'm relatively new to python I just want to consistently print them. The error is that the queue isn't working how it should. After putting and getting a few comments the queue is just empty for my "Producer" function. Here's my code:

```
import asyncio
import time
from asyncio import Queue
from TikTokLive import TikTokLiveClient
from TikTokLive.types.events import CommentEvent, ConnectEvent

#/Users/sunilpc/Documents/Python/tiktokTest.py

# Instantiate the client with the user's username
client: TikTokLiveClient = TikTokLiveClient(unique_id="@territorialwarfr")

# Comment Holders
commentQueue = asyncio.Queue()

# Define how you want to handle specific events via decorator
@client.on("connect")
async def on_connect(_: ConnectEvent):
    print("Connected to Room ID:", client.room_id)

# Notice no decorator?
@client.on("comment")
async def on_comment(event: CommentEvent):
    #print(f"{event.user.nickname} -> {event.comment}")
    await commentQueue.put(f"{event.user.nickname} -> {event.comment}\n")
    

# Define handling an event via "callback"
#client.add_listener("comment", on_comment)
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(client.start(), printQueue())
    #await client.start()
    #await printQueue()

async def printQueue():
    while True:
        if not commentQueue.empty():
            item = await commentQueue.get()
            print("Comment: {}".format(item))
        else:
            print("Waiting for new Comments...\n")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

and my output:

```
Waiting for new Comments...

Waiting for new Comments...

Waiting for new Comments...

Waiting for new Comments...

Connected to Room ID: 7181046628336356139
Comment: swift_sunsets -> 1

Comment: drosdye -> 1

Comment: what talent does charli have -> 1 2 3 4

Comment: what talent does charli have -> 1 2 3 4

Comment: I’m_paradox -> 1

Comment: I’m_paradox -> 1

Comment: Amir Morris -> 2

Waiting for new Comments...

Waiting for new Comments...

Waiting for new Comments...
```

I'm getting some comments from the queue but then it stops seeing comments and just prints "Waiting for new Comments..." forever.

I've tried to run the client.start() and printQueue() as different tasks using asyncio.create_task() but that also has the same result. Simply printing in the on_comment function works fine but I cant really use the comment data from that.